# What is clazz used for in "private static Class clazz = SnappyDecompressor.class" source file?

Tags: java, hadoop, java-native-interface, native

I am studying the compressor implementation (in Java) for Snappy, Zlib and others. Near the top of the source file is this line below. Can anyone explain to me what it means?

```
HACK - Use this as a global lock in the JNI layer
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "unused"})
private static Class clazz = SnappyDecompressor.class;
```

I understand, for example, in Snappy, SnappyDecompressor.java is essentially a wrapper for snappy C / native implementation, and to make calls to that C implementation, the Java layer makes calls through JNI interface.

The top part of the source for snappy (Java wrapper), SnappyDecompressor.java is here:

```
package org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.snappy;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Decompressor;

/**
 * A {@link Decompressor} based on the snappy compression algorithm.
 * http://code.google.com/p/snappy/
 */
public class SnappyDecompressor implements Decompressor {
  private static final Log LOG =
      LogFactory.getLog(SnappyCompressor.class.getName());
  private static final int DEFAULT_DIRECT_BUFFER_SIZE = 64 * 1024;

  // HACK - Use this as a global lock in the JNI layer
  @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "unused"})
  private static Class clazz = SnappyDecompressor.class;
```

[Full source](https://github.com/facebookarchive/hadoop-20/blob/2a29bc6ecf30edb1ad8dbde32aa49a317b4d44f4/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/snappy/SnappyDecompressor.java)

Comment: I am asking a genuine question with quest of learning. Can you explain to why you are immediately down-voting an honest question with no comment or explanation?

Comment: JNI is a way to run native code from Java. It sounds like they want to define a field, which the JNI code will reference, in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comment: it is used from the JNI layer, seemingly for some locking from the JNI layer. ([see the full Decompressor source](https://github.com/facebookarchive/hadoop-20/blob/2a29bc6ecf30edb1ad8dbde32aa49a317b4d44f4/src/native/src/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/snappy/SnappyDecompressor.c))

Lines 76, 77:

```
SnappyDecompressor_clazz = (*env)->GetStaticFieldID(env, clazz, "clazz",
                                                 "Ljava/lang/Class;");
```

Line 83:

```
jobject clazz = (*env)->GetStaticObjectField(env,thisj, SnappyDecompressor_clazz);
```

Lines 100 to 102:

```
LOCK_CLASS(env, clazz, "SnappyDecompressor");
const char* compressed_bytes = (const char*)(*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, compressed_direct_buf);
UNLOCK_CLASS(env, clazz, "SnappyDecompressor");
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like clazz is used as a mutex by the java layer to tell native code to lock/unlock a region of memory (in this case `compressed_direct_buf`),  which is "owned" by an instance of a java object (in this case, `SnappyDecompressor_clazz `).